# Contact form post and redirect not working

Tags: node.js, forms

**final edit**

Got it

Changed the route to

```
res.render('contact/thankyou', {
  pageTitle: 'Rafflefly | Thank You'
});
```

**Original question**

I am trying to create a contact form but I'm getting the following error:

[image]

Here is the code I have so far:

index.js

```
/* contact ROUTES. */
router.get('/contact', contacts_controller.contact_index);
router.post('/contact/send', contacts_controller.send_contact);
```

contacts_controller.js

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

exports.contact_index = function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('contact/contact', { title: 'Rafflefly | Contact' });
}

exports.send_contact = function(req, res, next) {
  const output = `
    <p>You have a new contact request from ${req.body.first_name} ${req.body.last_name} saying the following message:</p>
    <p>${req.body.message}</p>
  `;

  nodemailer.createTestAccount((err, account) => {
    // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "smtp.sendgrid.net",
        port: 587,
        auth: {
          user: process.env.SENDGRID_USERNAME,
          pass: process.env.SENDGRID_PASSWORD,
        }
      });
    } else {
      transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "smtp.ethereal.email",
        port: 587,
        auth: {
          user: 'qkkvnabtziufbksa@ethereal.email',
          pass: 'A4W9HF2WbhAav263VM',
        }
      });
    }
    // setup email data with unicode symbols
    let mailOptions = {
      from: process.env.GLOBAL_EMAIL || 'ben@benbagley.co.uk', // sender address
      to: `${req.body.email}`, // list of receivers
      subject: 'New contact request', // Subject line
      text: output
    };
    // send mail with defined transport object
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
      if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
      }

      console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
      console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

      // req.flash('success_msg', 'Your email has been sent!');
      res.redirect('thankyou', { title: 'Rafflefly | Thank You' });
    });
  });
}
```

file structure

[image: image #2]

As far as I can tell everything is set up correctly but obviously something is missing here.

*EDIT #1**

Here is the app.js file, this was a generated application using the express generator.

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var sassMiddleware = require('node-sass-middleware');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(sassMiddleware({
  src: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
  dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
  indentedSyntax: true, // true = .sass and false = .scss
  sourceMap: true
}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**EDIT #2**

I got the form working `form(class='w-full max-w-md m-auto p-8' action='/contact/send' method='POST')`

I also changed the redirect to this

```
  // req.flash('success_msg', 'Your email has been sent!');
  res.redirect(301, '/contact/thankyou', {
    title: 'Rafflefly | Thank You'
  })
```

But now the url is rendering like so `http://localhost:3000/contact/301` and not `http://localhost:3000/contact/thankyou`

Comment: Can you show your app.js?

Comment: See edit #1 @Lucas_Santos

Comment: Obviously, the route /contact/send is not called. Can you copy your HTML and check what URL your browser is calling?

Comment: Can you expand your file structure ? maybe the 'views' folder is inside a folder tree that need to be appointed

Comment: See second edit @Lucas_Santos

Comment: See second edit @DeadEye

Comment: update your routes please

Comment: The routes are the same @Lucas_Santos so no change is needed because there is nothing to change.

Comment: res.redirect() takes only two arguments, remove the third one. Does your form works now ?

Answer (score 0):

See question edits and the final top edit for the answer.